# Filter array of objects based on another array in data

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of 20 objects which I am getting from a database, each of them has an unique id. I also have an array of data with 2 ids. I want want to filter out only those 2 objects from the array of 20.

```
computed: {
    newHeros(){
      return this.getAllHeros.filter(newHero => {
        console.log(newHero.id);
        return newHero.id === this.heroForTab
      })
    }
  },


return {
   heroForTab: ['76NQjrYTdfbWN8xZOAvI', 'uDsm0BValBa31guJs10h']
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `Array.filter` to return what you need

```js
var heroForTab = ['76NQjrYTdfbWN8xZOAvI', 'uDsm0BValBa31guJs10h'];
var arr = [{
    id: '76NQjrYTdfbWN8xZOAvI',
    name: 'aaa'
  },
  {
    id: '1111',
    name: 'bbb'
  },
  {
    id: '2222',
    name: 'ccc'
  },
  {
    id: 'uDsm0BValBa31guJs10h',
    name: 'ddd'
  }
]

var result = arr.filter(item => {
  return heroForTab.includes(item.id)
})

console.log(result)
```